# per-page customization of the ion-nav-bar

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I would like to change the `background-color` of the `ion-nav-bar` of my Ionic 1 single page application, depending on the currently displayed view.

Starting from the default ionic code generator, the skeleton of the app is in the menu.html file, and each page has its own HTML template, and its own controller.

How can I enforce the `ion-nav-bar`'s `background-color` from either the HTML template or its controller?

btw, I have already successfully activated SASS if it may help.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

---

Well there are different ways to do this with Javascript. One way is

`<ion-nav-bar ng-style="{'background-color': $root.backgroundColor}">
</ion-nav-bar>`

Then in each view you want a different color, you could change the background color from the controller:

`$rootScope.backgroundColor = 'yellow'`

You could also use predefined classes that set the background color in css. Also change the class name in controller:

`$rootScope.backgroundClass = 'yellow-bg'`

`<ion-nav-bar ng-class="$root.backgroundClass">
</ion-nav-bar>`

or 
`<ion-nav-bar ng-class="{$root.backgroundClass: true}">
</ion-nav-bar>`

and in the css, define each background color with the respective class

`.yellow-bg {background-color: yellow}`
`.red-bg {background-color: red}`

If you want, you could create a directive for this.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Unfortunately it does not help.

Comment: Sorry, pressed enter too fast. Please wait a little for more details!

Comment: I used the class approach : 1) define some classes in ionic.app.scss with different background-color's. 2) add the ng-class thing in menu.html and set the rootScope accordingly. Nothing happens. However, if I set 'class="yellow-bg"' in menu.html, then it works. So it looks like the $root is not updated when $rootScope is updated in the controller. Also I have checked in the Chrome inspector, and it confirms my assumption. I tried $rootScope.$apply() but this launches an exception.

Comment: I think I understand why it does not work: the menu.html has no controller, so the angular stuff is not taken into account. Correct? Then would you have any other idea?

Comment: Sorry, me again... Actually I was wrong, it looks like the root view, embedding the navbar, does have a controller called AppCtrl. Then I don't understand why it does not work :-(

Comment: Sorry, I am digging this as much as I can, and getting crazy. What do you mean by "updated" ng-class options?

Comment: Strange thing that I have noticed: ng-class="'yellow-bg'" (double+single quotes) work in one of the menu-content templates (child view), but the exact same notation does not work in the ion-nav-bar. However, replacing it by class="yellow-bg" does work.

Comment: I finally got it to work with the alternate notation: <ion-nav-bar class="ng-class:$root.backgroundClass">. It's crazy, I don't understand what has happened, if you have any explanation I am interested. Thanks again anyway!